# Is there Liquid Haskell enabled Prelude?

Tags: haskell, haskell-prelude, liquid-haskell

Is there a annotated variant or Haskell Prelude available for easy migration of existing programs that call functions like `head` or `length`?

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the LH [Documentation](https://github.com/ucsd-progsys/liquidhaskell/README.md), you can augment existing files with `.spec` files that give just specifications of already existing code. LH itself comes with a large prelude (see the [include](https://github.com/ucsd-progsys/liquidhaskell/tree/master/include) folder) that includes specifications for lots of common stuff, including `head`, `length`, functions on `Data.Set`, etc.